# The best way to share telescope post on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-opengraph, telescope

I play with telescope (meteor open source project) and I want to share the post link instead of source link on Facebook; so I did,in the telescope-module-share package, something like this:

```
sourceLink: function(){
  return window.location.origin + "/posts/"+this._id;
},
```

It works great, except when I share the post on Facebook, it display the title and description of home page instead of the post shared!!

Anyone have an idea to fix it, please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Server Side Rendering, there's a great package for this : https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr

Comment: I did it but nothing !! when I deploy the app in the new adress it works but not on the existing adress